# wine on ubuntu 16.04: Unable to install a .msi file, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: 16.04, wine, vulkan

This is my third time trying to install Wine on Ubuntu 16.04 to install a .msi windows program (Ableton live 10).

I followed these steps:

```
  739  sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
  740  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
  741  sudo apt-get update
  742  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
  743  winecfg
```

Everything goes well and as it should (no error messages). But then on trying to install the Setup.msi file nothing happens and this error prompts:

```
wine msiexec /i ./Setup.msi 

0050:err:vulkan:wine_vk_init Failed to load libvulkan.so.1.
0078:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
```

I can't find any relevant links for solving these error messages for ubuntu. Looks like it needs some vulkan drivers of some kind. This is never mentioned in any installation tutorials (and I would really like to avoid installing extra graphic drivers, as I have no intention of gaming on this system).

Any hints, suggestions appreciated..!

EDIT:

After installing vulkan with

```
sudo apt install vulkan-utils
```

The error is now:

```
0078:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
003c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
00bc:fixme:file:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
00bc:fixme:file:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
00bc:fixme:file:server_ioctl_file Unsupported ioctl 24000 (device=2 access=1 func=0 method=0)
0024:fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
```

Comment: See if this helps https://www.tekbyte.net/2019/how-to-install-ableton-live-10-on-linux-with-wine-it-works-flawlessly/

Comment: @Raffles thank you for the comment. First time I tried I did it with that link, as it is by far the simplest (Nothing more than a sudo apt install wine ..) , which led to the exact same errors

Comment: Seems to be related to USB functionality on some level. [Possibly relevant](https://superuser.com/q/1477796/928285) Q/A about properly setting up USB-connected devices so Wine can *attempt* to work with them.